# Laravel installation Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url

Tags: laravel, proxy, http-proxy, malformed

I am facing this problem when I try to install Laravel on my Windows machine; how can I solve this problem?

Changed current directory to `C:/Users/masab/AppData/Roaming/Composer`

> [ComposerDownloaderTransportException] Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url

> require [–dev] [–dry-run] [–prefer-source] [–prefer-dist] [–fixed] [–no-suggest] [–no-progress] [–no-update] [–no-install] [–no-scripts] [–update-no-dev] [-w|–update-with-dependencies] [-W|–update-with-all-dependencies] [–with-dependencies] [–with-all-dependencies] [–ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [–ignore-platform-reqs] [–prefer-stable] [–prefer-lowest] [–sort-packages] [-o|–optimize-autoloader] [-a|–classmap-authoritative] [–apcu-autoloader] [–apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [–] []…

Comment: Please share more details - what do you do to trigger that problem? Is this even related to Laravel itself?

Comment: i don't see this type of problem before when i am trying to install laravel then i face this problem i use laravel luman for webapi but i don't face this problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing this error for below command on my Windows system for install laravel.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

This is global command you can run this from any path on CMD ( command prompt )
but after install wamp or xampp server then **http_proxy** environment veritable created in your administatory system

```
 Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Veriables -> http_proxy
```

**Method 1:** Delete http_proxy Veriable and run again the same command from any path. then its works fine.

OR

**Method 2:** keep the http_proxy Veriable as it is. and open your project directory on CMD ( command prompt ) and run laravel/installer command in your project directory.

My project example : D:>cd wamp\www\laraveldemo

after this enter your command and run it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you clicked on HTTP proxy and set the wrong value while installing your composer.
To solve this bug, go to the system environment file (Simply type env in your search and open). Once you open it, you'll find an HTTP option, click on it and delete it. After this, restart your System and reinstall Composer. This time, do not select the HTTP proxy.

Otherwise, set the correct value to the HTTP proxy.

After installation, try rerunning your laravel command and the problem will be solved. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to use a proxy, here's a working configuration with properly formed URLs:

```bash
export use_proxy=yes
export http_proxy=http://jambon:CzZZmX8YHGNG3SJ@198.51.100.38:3128
export https_proxy=http://jambon:CzZZmX8YHGNG3SJ@198.51.100.38:3128
```

`jambon` is the username, `CzZZmX8YHGNG3SJ` is the password, `198.51.100.38` is the proxy host, and `3128` is the proxy port.

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy to resolve this problem.

1. Open system environment variable
2. Go to User Environment section.
3. Find http_proxy variable, select, and delete.
4. Restart server

***Boom your issue resolved now.***

Further more you can also follow the below images to solve your issue.

- Type env variable in start bar and select **Edit system environment** option

[image]

- Click on Environment variables

[image]

- Go User variable section and find http_proxy or a similar variable.

[image]

- Click on http_proxy and press delete button below, and Press Ok Ok to save setting for both windows.

Make sure to restart your server, That's it.