# when i run composer require laravel/ui this command

Tags: http-proxy

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer global require laravel/ui
```

Comment: it didn't work  same problem appear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302451/18078362  try this then....

Answer (score 0):

You can try by deleting http_proxy to navigate this path: Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Veriables -> http_proxy.
Then run the command again.

Or You can keep http_proxy as it is and navigate to your project directory(copy the directory path) and past the path over cmd then execute the command again.

Hope that both step will work.

Comment: i had already done it but didn't workout